# assigning an alphanumeric value to a variable in batch

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd

I want to assign the alpha numeric value to one variable in Batch scripting.
I tried following one but getting error.

```
setlocal
set test = \765514e2aad02ca658cc56cdb7884947 *E:\\test1
echo %test%
endlocal

Error:
C:\Users\bgannu>setlocal

C:\Users\bgannu>set   test = \765514e2aad02ca658cc56cdb7884947 *E:\\test1

C:\Users\bgannu>echo 0
0

C:\Users\bgannu>endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for set is `set [[/a [expression]] [/p [variable=]] string]`
The  `=` has to be directly after your variable so you need to change:

```
set test = \765514e2aad02ca658cc56cdb7884947 *E:\\test1
```

to:

```
set test=\765514e2aad02ca658cc56cdb7884947 *E:\\test1
```

Otherwise your variable name would have a space at the end. You can easily try this out:

```
> set bar = foo
> echo %bar%
%bar%
> echo %bar %
 foo
```

Note that both the variable name *and* its content got a space.

Comment: +1 for the correct issue; I took the liberty of making the actual problem a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the /A. the /A is used for arithmetic.

```
C:\test>set  var=\765514e2aad02ca658cc56cdb7884947 *E:\\test1

C:\test>echo %var%
\765514e2aad02ca658cc56cdb7884947 *E:\\test1
```